# Fixed Div on Scroll, but not over footer

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular

I need a div to change position to fixed after scrolling the heading out of view. But i also need the div not to go over the footer at the bottom.
I started with an angular directive for the first part but cant figure out how to prevent the div from going over the footer.

I tried adding some jquery, but it does not work perfectly plus i wanted a pure angular solution if poosible:

```
 var a=$(document).scrollTop()+window.innerHeight;
 var b=$('#footer').offset().top;

          if($('#cart').offset().top + $('#cart').height()
            >= $('#footer').offset().top - 20){
            $( "#cart" ).removeClass( "top-position-cart" )
            $('#cart').css('bottom', (10+(a-b))+'px');
          }else{
              $( "#cart" ).addClass( "fixed-cart" );
            }
```

```
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                offset: '@',
                scrollClass: '@'
            },
            link: function (scope, element) {
                angular.element($window).bind('scroll', function () {
                    if (this.pageYOffset >= parseInt(scope.offset)) {
                        element.addClass(scope.scrollClass);
                  } else {
                        element.removeClass(scope.scrollClass);
                  }
                });
            }
        };
```

```html
  <div id="cart" change-class-on-scroll offset="380" 
       scroll-class="fixed-cart top-position-cart>

  </div>
```

```
.fixed-cart {
    position: fixed;
}
.top-position-cart {
  top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Please share some code snippet or fiddle for clarification. Thanks